# Multiple label placement constraints in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, docker-stack

When I give multiple label placement constraints and deploy the stack, the services are not running in either of the mentioned constraints.

Ex:

```
deploy:
    mode: global
    placement: 
        constraints: 
            - node.labels.type == test  
            - node.labels.type == prod
    restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

But if I give only one constraint (any one) then it is working in that label node.

I have seen the same [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#placement). The difference is there are two kinds of constraints (node type and label) are used. But I used only one kind (label).

Is it allowed to use same kind of constraints. If it is how to use it.

**Update**

Ex:

```
deploy:
    mode: global
    placement: 
        constraints: 
            - node.hostname == server1  
            - node.hostname == server2
    restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

Now this should run the service on both servers. But the service is not at all starting.

Answer (score 4):

What happens with that configuration is that you try to deploy to a server where the label `type` is BOTH (not either) `"test"`and `"prod"`. That is not going to work.

If you need these `"test"` and `"prod"` labels elsewhere, your option is to create a third label, for example `"foo"`:

`docker node update --label-add foo=bar NODE`

Then you can use that in your constraints:

```
constraints:
    - node.labels.foo == bar
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I will update it to make it simple.

Comment: @RamIdavalapati Your example has the same problem. That will not run it on both servers. If you have only those two servers, remove the whole constraints-block. `mode: global` ensures that the container runs on all of your nodes.